# Why am I Read Access violation Error?

Tags: c++, stl

I am running the below C++ program in visual studio 2015 environment in debug mode.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<vector<int>> my_2d_array;
    int total_entries = 10;

    // initialising my 2d vector
    for (int arr_index = 0; arr_index < total_entries; ++arr_index) {
        my_2d_array.push_back(*(new vector<int>()));
    }

    // doing something with my 2d array

    // de-initialsing my 2d vector
    for (vector<vector<int>>::iterator itr = my_2d_array.begin();
        itr != my_2d_array.end(); ++itr) {
        delete &(*itr); // <-- ***CULPRIT LINE. Donno if its legal?***
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run above program I am getting Read access violation error< Need to know why? I know delete + iterator combination is not a recommended, but not getting a clue why my code is crashing in the afore-commented culprit line.

Comment: `my_2d_array.push_back(*(new vector<int>()));` Should be: `my_2d_array.push_back(vector<int>());` or you could just do: `vector<vector<int>> my_2d_array(total_entries);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete &(*itr);` is ill-formed; the elements and storage are created and management by the `vector`, you can't `delete` them directly.

And `my_2d_array.push_back(*(new vector<int>()));` leads to memory leak. You created a `vector` object via `new`, it's copied to construct the element to be inserted into `my_2d_array`. After that the object is lost, we can't `delete` it again.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take care of the mem_leak.